# CSS3 Animations With Keyframes Buggy On Safari Mobile?

Tags: ios, css, safari, css-transitions

I have set up a `keyframe` with does a `translate` and `scale`.

This works beautifully on `Chrome` and works 80% of the times on `Safari` as well.

But during those 20% of the times on safari, either a `scale` works or a `translate` works.

My requirement is to have both of them in unison.

Here is an example code.

```
@keyframes left-swipe {
    from {
        transform: translateX(-100%) scaleY(0.67);
    }
    to {
        transform: translateX(0px) scaleY(1);
    }
}
.right {
    animation-duration: 0.5s;
    animation-name: left-swipe;
}
```

I'm using `POSTCSS` and hence prefixing will happen automatically.

Using the latest `Safari` on iOS 9.2.

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Where is your problem code?

Comment: Whoops, forgot. Will post a example css.

Comment: Posted. You can now check.